# Problems with multiples private sites in Liferay 6.2

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I need to create 2 private sites in Liferay 6.2. I have already created one of them, that has been built as the private side of the portal (site 1). I have created the another private site (site 2). The problem I am facing is that I cannot log in and go straight to the new site (site 2). Instead of that I always get logged in in the private side (site 1), as well as the new private site (site 2). In other words, when I log in I can see both private sites, and I cannot not remove the first private site (private side of the portal). 
This woudl be the site structure:

```
Liferay Portal
    |- Private site 1 (private side of the portal, strikethrough eye icon)
    |- Private site 2
```

I guess I am not working properly with private sites. Maybe site 1 needs to be something different from the "private side" of the portal? Do I need to move content from site 1 to another site and leave site 1 empty?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

In Liferay you cant log in only to one site, you are being logged to the portal instance that contains sites. You have to create new instance in control panel in order to achieve two independent sites.

Comment: Maybe my mistake is to use the private pages of the portal as a site?. So when you log in in the portal, you will see the private pages and sites you can see. What I need is to loging in the portal and see the sites you can see and hide the private pages of the portal. Is it possible or should I move the private pages content to a new site?

Comment: Maybe solution to your problem would be site membership. You can create sites and restric access to them to certain users.